# how to use cron.php without setting in control panel?

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, cron

Is this possible to run and use cron.php without set command in cronjob in control panel or shell ?

I have crontab in my config.xml file and need to use it but want my module run cron without setting anything

Is this possible ?

I saw link below before : [www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

Comment: I don't think it's possible :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview

Comment: Is there any php command that I can use in my module for run cron instead of set cronjob ?

Comment: In theory you can use `system()` or `exec()` function to fire command in the shell, ie. `exec('/bin/sh path/to/cron.sh')`. It may not work if the php settings on the server forbids from using those functions (and usually it does forbid using them)

Answer (score 1):

[magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job#other_solutions) tells us

> If you do not have access to crontab on your service, you can set up the page that needs to be run periodically as a Home Page in you personal computer browser http://example.com/yourmagentofolder/cron.php. Every time you open a new window or tab, it will execute the scheduled task(s) on your server.

but i would not recommend that kind of idiotic hint ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You must set cron from system because Magento can't trigger cron jobs without it. If you don't want configure it on shell or panel you could use external service e.g. https://www.easycron.com/

Answer (score 0):

In desperate times, you can configure `curl` or `wget` to be run from `task scheduler` (Windows) or *nix/mac as a cron job on a workstation or server you control.

Have it access `http://example.com/pathifused/cron.php` every fifteen minutes and you have a remote cron trigger to run Magento's internal cron.

However, the best is to either run `cron.sh` from your cPanel cron jobs or if not allowed to run shell scripts from cron by arbitrary security rules enacted by your hosting provider, run:

```
php /path/to/httpdocroot/pathifused/cron.php
```

And, yes, I've used this when the sheer vileness of getting the Magento cron system to work reared it's ugly head. Using the external triggering created jobs I could view using a Magento Cron Table monitor script till I could determine that the php interpreter being used by cron commands was not the same as interactive or lsphp and was failing with an error. And later when some changes to cPanel/WHM enacted draconian security that banned shell scripts from being run by cron.